# .NET - Adding an extra style sheet to a razor view ontop of layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a new view and I want to add some custom CSS, so I created a new CSS sheet in the content folder called ClientDetails and referenced it at the top of the sheet as I read on another thread of adding specific CSS sheets to a view:

```
@model Linkofy.Models.Client

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

@section Styles {
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ClientDetails.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}

<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.clientN)</h2>
```

However with the @section Styles bit I get this error:

> System.Web.HttpException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Styles".

Though if I remove the @section styles bit it works fine, I wondered if its only rendering that sheet and not the layout CSS if it's overriding it or something? how do I add it on top of all the other sheets needed for the display.

I have tried looking around for the answer to this though if it is a duplicate please link me to the question and I will close it, thanks!

Comment: Do you have a `@RenderSection("Styles", false)` in your layout file?  Also, you should bundle your stylesheet and use `Styles.Render("[bundleName]")` in the section.

Comment: @Bardicer When I add this it doesn't work either I don't know if me specifying that sheet disconnects the layout file from the sheet perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   **The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Styles".**
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Styles".

Solution:

In your ~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml render the section using

```
    @RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg537886(v=vs.111).aspx for more details.

Also you must declare the layout:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
```

Comment: Instead of making a section for styles I suggest adding all your styles in the BundleConfig.cs in the App_Start folder.

Comment: Ahh i got it!! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is explained in the message. You probably have something like this in your layout page:

```
@RenderSection("Styles")
```

When you use it like that, it's required by default. **Every** page will be **required** to have the additional `style` section. Otherwise, you get the error you are seeing now. What you need to do is make that section *not* required:

```
@RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
```

Comment: I think you've got that the wrong way round. The problem is that the OP *doesn't* have that `RenderSection` directive but has declared that section in their view with `@section`. So the view has a section but no idea what to do with it.

Comment: @Matt Yeah I've given this a go and I still get the same error. My layout file also references all the bootstrap files so I would like to keep them in but add this additional CSS sheet, the only way I can think of is starting a new folder containing all the files I need for it but then I will have duplicates. Sorry quite new to styling on VS!